# Google Apps Script iframe refused to display

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-apps-script, x-frame-options

I have a Google Sheet with a bound Google Apps Script (GAS) that creates a modal dialog box (popup) in HTML/JS as a user-friendly "frontend" to my Google Sheet, which is like a Database for Dummies.

It's been fine since I finished the current version a few months ago. All of a sudden, when it tries to make a server-side function call, the whole popup goes blank. The console log shows this error:

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&conti…ndler%28loadFullItemLite%29.withUserObject%28this%29.sendAllItems%28%29%3B' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Note that `loadFullItemLite()` is a [successHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) that runs `withUserObject(this)` when `sendAllItems()` returns the requested data (i.e. `this`).

The issue seems to be that it won't display a **ServiceLogin** page, not that it won't display my popup content. It's getting stuck trying to log into the Service, but what service? and why?

I have 3 users with 3 different Google accounts all running the same scripts in the same sheets with the same access levels. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using HTML?  Are you setting the sandbox mode?  Are you using UI Service?  UI Service is deprecated.  NATIVE Sandbox mode with HTML Service is now deprecated.  You need to show your code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @SandyGood. Yes, it's HTML and JS and I'm using sandbox mode iframe. It was working fine until yesterday, but I can't find any news of GAS changes as of June 10, 2016.  Do you know why it's trying to go to the ServiceLogin page?

Comment: I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the setting of your app script.

go to publish-> deploys as webapp->change version to new

and change who can access the scripts to myself to list of person(user) in your case list 3 users of yours

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can't deploy it as a web app because it's bound to the Google sheets. The weird part is that I am the owner of the sheet and the script, but I can't use the script while my 2 other users can!

Comment: Is Google app script telling you .. "YOU SHALL NOT PASS" ?? :D